# how to determine ID of list <li> by list item number

Tags: jquery, css, list, html-lists, element

So I have a list

```
<ul id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable">
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 1</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 2</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 3</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 4</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 5</li>
</ul>
```

Ans as you can see the id of this ul is #sortable1. Now, what then is the id of the `<li>` element containing the word Item 2?

```
<script>
$( "__LIST ITEM ID___" ).click(function() {
  $( this ).addClass( "big-blue", 1000, "easeOutBounce" );
});
</script>
```

I am sure this is a simple one, but i can't seem to find an easy tutorial out there.

Best, 
Will

Comment: "what then is the id of the < LI > element containing the word Item 2". None of your li elements even have IDs.

Comment: thats easy, your id for all of them is `undefined`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your terminology is incorrect.  You are looking for the *selector* -- id is just one type of selector.

You can select the second `li` element using the [nth-child selector](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/): `#sortable1 li:nth-child(2)`.  So your code would be:

```
$( "#sortable1 li:nth-child(2)" ).click(function() {
  $( this ).addClass( "big-blue", 1000, "easeOutBounce" );
});
```

Comment: can you enter a wildcard for the NUMBER of the child? so that it creates an effect like this on ALL nth-children?

Comment: Say you want to do something for every 3rd li, you could do `li:nth-child(3n)`. Is that what you're looking for?

Answer (score 2):

This isn't using the ID, but it's a simple solution:

```
$( "li:contains(Item 2)" ).click(function() {
  $( this ).addClass( "big-blue", 1000, "easeOutBounce" );
});
```

Use the `:contains()` selector to find the text within the li.

It should be noted that anything after the first comma in `addClass` won't do anything, but I left it in to keep in sync with your code.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TxAzH/)

Comment: ah, that would be really helpful but I was incomplete in my question. 

The LI item will actually hold much more than just the words "Item 2" but that was my example content. So I will need another way to get the element. Is there a selector that gets it like by

1st, 2nd, 3rd, and so pn?

Answer (score 0):

You could also use an index of the li.

```
$('li.ui-state-default:eq(2)').click(function(){
       $(this).addClass( "big-blue", 1000, "easeOutBounce" );
});
```